# Iterating over two lists one after another

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iteration

I have two lists `list1` and `list2` of numbers, and I want to iterate over them with the same instructions. Like this:

```
for item in list1:
  print(item.amount)
  print(item.total_amount)

for item in list2:
  print(item.amount)
  print(item.total_amount)
```

But that feels redundant. I know I can write `for item in list1 + list2:`, but it has a price of running-time.

Is there a way do that without loose time?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This can be done with **[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)**:

```
import itertools

l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for i in itertools.chain(l1, l2):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Which will print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

As per the documentation, `chain` does the following:

> Make an iterator that returns elements from the first iterable until it is exhausted, then proceeds to the next iterable, until all of the iterables are exhausted.

If you have your lists in a list, **[`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)** is available:

```
l = [l1, l2]
for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(l):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

Which yields the same result.

If you don't want to import a module for this, writing a function for it is pretty straight-forward:

```
def custom_chain(*it):
    for iterab in it:
        yield from iterab
```

This requires Python 3, for Python 2, just `yield` them back using a loop:

```
def custom_chain(*it):
    for iterab in it:
        for val in iterab:
            yield val
```

In addition to the previous, Python `3.5` with its extended unpacking generalizations, also allows unpacking in the list literal:

```
for i in [*l1, *l2]:
    print(i, end=" ")
```

though this is slightly faster than `l1 + l2` it still constructs a list which is then tossed; only go for it as a final solution.

Comment: If i will add 'if' condition with 'break' inside loop and it would be trigger in first list, the second one will not run, right?

Answer (score 16):

`chain` works, but if you feel that it's overkill to import a module just to call a single function once, you can replicate its behavior inline:

```
for seq in (list1, list2):
  for item in seq:
    print(item.amount)
    print(item.total_amount)
```

Creating the (list1, list2) tuple is O(1) with respect to list length, so it should perform favorably in comparison to concatenating the lists together.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
for item in list1 + list2:
    print(item.amount)
    print(item.total_amount)
```

Only 3 lines

Comment: I think that would concatenate the list into a newly created list, which would be expensive.

Comment: From the question: *"I know I can write `for item in list1 + list2:`"*

Answer (score 0):

After several executions, the fastest alternative was the second one.

```
import itertools
from time import time

l1 = list(range(1000))
l2 = list(range(1000))

print('Alternative 1. Itertools')
t = time()
for j in range(10000):
    s = 0
    for i in itertools.chain(l1, l2):
        s += i
print(time() - t)

print('Alternative 2. Naive')
t = time()
for j in range(10000):
    s = 0
    for i in [*l1, *l2]:
        s += i
print(time() - t)

print('Alternative 3. Yield')
def chain(*ls):
    for l in ls:
        for k in l:
            yield k
t = time()
for j in range(10000):
    s = 0
    for i in chain(l1, l2):
        s += i
print(time() - t)
```